# TASM graphic mode

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, bios, tasm

When switching from text mode to graphic mode the resulting screen shows on the top left the C:\Tasm\Bin> figure. I have no idea why it does this, all I do is call the graphics mode interrupt.

the code is:

```
mov ax, 13h
int 10h
```

The resulting screen is this:
[image]

Also, I can continue running commands by typing them.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you've just returned to DOS with the new video mode.  What were you expecting to have happen?  What's your complete program?  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Also, I presume you are running this in an emulator?  Which one?

Comment: The 'polite' thing to do is to first call The `0Fh` function of int `10h` which gets the current display mode, and then set the display back to that mode before you exit from the program.

Comment: @Nate Eldrege I am sorry for not providing enough exmaples. I am trying to create a version of the UNO game. My complete program is quite long as I call many different functions. However, I don't think it is relevant as these work fine.. After switching to graphic mode I expected to see a completely black screen, without anything on it. I believe that this is the problematic part.

Comment: @Nate Eldrege What do you mean by the new video mode?

Comment: 320x200, 256 colors.  Isn't that what you requested?  I expect that immediately after you set the video mode, the screen *was* blank, but then your program exited and DOS displayed its prompt.  If you did not intend for your program to exit, then you need to investigate why it did that.  What was your program supposed to do after setting the video mode?

Comment: @Nate Eldrege  You are right, the program exited immediately after executing the graphic mode and a few other function, therefore the figure. I added a loop that while no input is entered it doesn't exit and it indeed doesn't show this figure. Thank you!